# Entity Framework Datetime Precision

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem that I've been banging my head on.  I inherited a project at work that uses SQL Server and Web Forms without EF, and I am rewriting using ASP.NET MVC and EF.  Whenever I get a record out of the database, it seems to do this fine.  However, when I want to add or update a record, errors are being thrown on the columns that use datetime because of precision.  I've been reading and people are saying that the value in the database needs to be changed to datetime2, but at this point I don't think that would be a good option.  Is there something I can do in the project itself to set the datetime precision to 3?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: The original `DATETIME` in SQL Server does have a **3.33ms** precision - there's nothing you can do to change that. If you need better precision, you *need to switch* your database datatype to `DATETIME2(n)` - no way around that. So either you can live with the current precision with all its restrictions - or you need to switch. Take your pick.

Comment: Alright, I ended up changing the column to datetime2.  Thank you!